# How to find possible constant value conditions for linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

Reference: Exercise 1.24 of Linear Algebra by Jim Hefferon

What conditions must the constants, the b’s, satisfy so that the
system has a solution?

```
x − 3y = b1

3x + y = b2

x + 7y = b3

2x + 4y = b4
```

I solution given to this problem is

```
 this system is consistent if and only if both b3 = −2b1 + b2 and
b4 = −b1 + b2
```

The details for the solution can be seen here on page 12: http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/jhanswer.pdf

I want to know why it is not necessary to also say that `b1 = -b3 + b4` should be satisfied. Basically, how does one reach a conclusion as to how many conditions are required to be satisfied when approaching these kind of problems?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Do you see that if $b3=-2b1+b2$ and $b4=-b1+b2$ then $-b3+b4=b1$?

Comment: I think we need to find the relation beetwen $b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4$, from two condition above we can get your condition, and we can replace one of them by your condition

Comment: Thanks. That's so silly of me.

Comment: Is there a way to know how many conditions would be required if there was also a equation with b5 constant?

Comment: Since you have two unknowns, the superfluous equations need to be the same as a combinaison of the first two. Then if you had a fifth equation, you would have needed a third condition, $5$ equations minus $2$ unknowns.